# C++ std::string is 100% RAII on any platform?

Tags: c++, string, raii

As I know, std::string is a RAII object so I don't need to initialize after declaration. The constructor will take care of this stuff automatically. But is there any exception on any platform or any compiler ?

```
class TestString
{
public:
    TestString()
    {
        // m_str.clear(); or
        // m_str = "";
    }
    virtual ~TestString(){}

private:
    std::string m_str;
};
```

Very simple question, thanks !

Comment: RAII doesn't really have anything to do with objects being initialized in their default constructors as opposed to having to manually set properties after you initialize something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default constructor for `std::string` constructs an empty string, with a length of zero characters. That is the guarantee offered by the default constructor on all platforms for all implementations.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes. It is the guarantee offered by the standard and all conforming implementations need to abide to it.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, initialisation may involve several method calls *after* construction, but this doesn't violate RAII. It's the constructors responsibility to get the object into a self-consistent valid state - in particular, one where it's safe to call the destructor or any other method. Depending on your requirements, this may mean nothing more than setting some variables to zero.

So why the big fuss about RAII? Well, the original point of RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialisation) related to exception safety.

When a function exits early, in particular due to an exception throw, it's important that destructors are called - that resources (heap memory and file handles, for example) are released. C++ mandates that destructor calls occur automatically when a variable goes out of scope for that reason. However, an exception throw can happen at any time, at least in principle. How can you be sure that the resource you want to release has even been allocated? If your not sure that that allocation will have been done you could use a flag or a null handle or similar so you can test in the destructor, but how can you be sure that flag has been initialised?

Basically, in order to be able to call a destructor safely, C++ needs to know that the object has been initialised. That is handled by the constructor. But that just leads to another subtle issue - what happens if an exception throw occurs *inside* the constructor.

Long story short - C++ takes responsibility for the destructor call only after the constructor has successfully completed. If the constructor is exited early by an exception throw, there will be no destructor call - if exceptions haven't been handled carefully (or proven impossible) within the constructor, memory and/or resource leaks may occur.

Anyway, the origin of the name is simply that resources aren't considered to have been acquired unless the constructor has completed, therefore freeing resources (by calling the destructor) should occur if and only if the constructor completed successfully.

That's a simple model, though, and the name can be misleading. In practice, resources can be acquired by any method, and the language has no fixed ideas about which kinds of activity are initialisation and which aren't. The important thing is that, if an exception is thrown at an awkward moment and your objects destructor is called as a result, it should always be able to determine exactly what cleanup is needed - which resources to release.

Constructing an object in a self-consistent state isn't a difficult job - it may require no more than setting some member variables to zero. In fact some people *strongly* recommend that you do no more than this in most classes, the reason being that setting a few POD member variables to zero cannot trigger an exception throw - you don't have to worry about catching and rethrowing exceptions and cleaning up that semi-constructed object.

Every standard library class that has a destructor will meet that self-consistent state requirement. Only "Plain Old Data" types (e.g. `int`) which by definition don't have destructors (well, no *useful* destructors at least) don't implement RAII, at least not for themselves.